# How to open file via intent right after downloading?

Tags: java, android

I need to open downloaded file by any relevant activity outside my app.

I download file via `DownloadManager` to default folder `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`

I registered `BroadcastReceiver` in my activity, which shall to open file right after download via intent:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        if (downloadManager != null) {
            Cursor c = downloadManager.query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId));
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                    String uriString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                    Intent openIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    openIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(uriString), getMimeType(uriString));
                    openIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(openIntent, "Выберите приложение"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But right after downloading I got an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent
caused by android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/sample-20.pdf exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Use a FileProvider to serve your file.

Comment: could u provide any example or point with link?

Comment: Google for android fileprovider example.

Comment: Or read stackoverflow pages tagged `fileprovider`.

Answer (score 1):

Correct way to open downloaded file with `FileProvider`

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        if (downloadManager != null) {
            Cursor c = downloadManager.query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId));
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                    String uriString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                    Intent openIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    File file = new File(URI.create(uriString));
                    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", file);
                    openIntent.setDataAndType(uri, getMimeType(uriString));
                    openIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(openIntent, "Выберите приложение"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

String getMimeType(String path) {
    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(path);
    if (extension != null) {
        type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    return type;
}
```